# Why can't windows find my drive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, sata

For a couple of years, I've had an SSD and an optical drive installed into the computer.

It's an old SSD, so it's small, and I realized that I had an HDD lying around, so I put it in, and it didn't show up in my computer, and I also checked that it didn't show up in disk management or device manager.

Thinking it was either power or data cables, I swapped both, and the HDD showed up just fine, but the optical drive stopped working. Thinking it might be a fault of the port on the motherboard I swapped it into the 4th empty SATA slot, to no avail.

It does appear to be port based, not count based. As in, if I unplug one, but plug the other into slot 3 or 4, neither are recognized, but it is still found in the bios.

But while it was booting I thought I saw all 3 drives listed during boot.

So I went into the BIOS on my next reboot, and noticed that the BIOS detected all 3 drives, but when I continued the normal boot, windows still didn't recognize the 3rd SATA drive.

Is there some configuration I might be missing to get the additional drive to show up in Windows? I looked around the BIOS to see anything like that, but all SATA ports were configured identically (with the exception of one of them being specified as boot.)

Update:

It does appear to be linked to 2 of the SATA ports on the motherboard. Both are recognized in the BIOS, but devices plugged into either of them do not show up in Windows.

Disk Manager Rescan doesn't appear to get the other to appear either.

Comment: "Thinking it was either power or data cables, I swapped both, and the HDD showed up just fine" So what's the issue?

Comment: @Ploni Oh, sorry that wasn't clear. Now: "swapped both->Optical drive stopped working"